# Spring MockMvc : setting MultiPartFile as part of form

Tags: spring, file, testing, case, mockmvc

My controller is like below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected String processSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("binaryUploadForm") BinaryUploadForm form, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
```

then I loop through files

```
    final int numberOfFiles = form.getFiles().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
        final MultipartFile multipartFile = form.getFiles().get(i);
```

I want to write a test case for this using MockMvc of spring.

```
mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/binary-management/add-binary.html").file(file)
```

is not helpful as multipartfile is not coming as part of parameter but as a field in form.

Can you please help.

Replies to comments:

in JSP I have a field like below

```
<input id="files0" type="file" name="files[0]" style="font-size:1.2em;height:22px;position:static;" size="48"/>
```

and form implementation is as below

```
public List<MultipartFile> getFiles() {
    return files;
}


public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {
    this.files = files;
}
```

html form is submitted using javascript which is quite complex and using EXT JS

Comment: Please explain how it comes as a field in form.

Comment: Can you show to us your BinaryUploadForm implementation?

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis and Dani please see my ammendment above. I added to original question as I had problem formatting reply.

Comment: I have raised a JIRA on spring dashboard to get this feature. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11965